# jquery spinner widget up/down events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm able to add to total price each time i increment up.  No luck decreasing total when going down.

> ```
>       $(".spinner").spinner({
>               change: function(){
>                   var total = $('#total').text();
>                   var num = $('.spinner').val();
>                   var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(6)').text();
>                   var newprice = price.replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '');             
>                   var itemTotal = (num - (num - 1)) * newprice;   
>                   total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(itemTotal);
>                   document.getElementById('total').textContent = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
>           }           });
> ```

I wrote an alert to listen for the event.  Which turned out to be spinchange.  None of the events listed from the jquery ui spinner site work. Is there a way I can check for spinchange up?  spinchange down?

Answer (score 1):

You could also bind to the `spin` event, based on the docs you can get the latest value from the second argument.

```
spin: function (event, ui) {
    ...
    var num = ui.value;
    ...
}
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-spin